# animation completion called immediately completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios8

I am now confused a lot .

This condition is normal when the value yes animation action .
But state when no value completion called immediately.

I do not know if there is any difference between the two .

```
- (void)setDimView : (UIView*)targetView state:(BOOL)state
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIView *dim = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];
    dim.tag = TAG;
    if (state)
    {
       dim.alpha = 0.0;
    }


    [UIView transitionWithView:dim duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^ {
        if (state)
        {
            [targetView setHidden:NO];
            [targetView addSubview:dim];

            dim.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            dim.alpha = 0.6;
        }
        else
        {
            dim.alpha = 0.0;

        }
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (!state)
        {
            for (UIView *subview in [targetView subviews])
            {
                if (subview.tag == TAG)
                {
                    [subview removeFromSuperview];
                    [targetView setHidden:YES];
                }
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This block working sequence is first it called animation block and then completion block, but if you are set animation NO then its immediately call to completion.

I am not getting why you are so confused about it?

Answer (score 0):

### Difference between animation block and completion block

The code inside the **animation block** called as a loop. if a view's frame change is set in animation block it will execute as animation it take a duration to execute your code which you can configure. but if you are setting this view's frame change in **completion block** this will execute in single stretch after the completion of animation.